# Sensor for measuring alcohol content of wine

Tags: wine, measurements, alcohol

I would like to know if there is a sensor that can monitor its alcohol content and displaying it to my LCD display.

Your answers would be a great help to my dreams. I'm a computer engineer taking my research Subject.

Comment: Are you hoping to monitor the alcohol content continuously throughout fermentation (where, for example, gravity readings could be taken and the alcohol percentage estimated) or are you hoping for something that can give a digital alcohol percentage for an arbitrary sample of wine? To make sure answers will actually help you, you may want to consider editing your question to include more details about what specifically you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

There are relatively affordable devices (iSpindel and TILT) that continuously report specific gravity wirelessly. You can use the data to derive the alcohol content with a pretty good degree of accuracy.

It's not exactly what you asked for but it wouldn't be too hard to make it work the way you want.

Comment: If the gravity sensor was on an arduino (for example) then the arduino could be programmed to store the OG with a button press, and then calculate and display the ABV from the current gravity. It could also do temperature corrections with a thermometer probe as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

There are sensors that do this.  I am not personally familiar with their accuracy, maintenance or robustness.
I am aware of this type of device from Anton-Paar

https://www.anton-paar.com/us-en/products/group/alcohol-meter/?ref=adwords&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8NbFgYKb4gIVV4ezCh0fUAdfEAAYASAAEgLswfD_BwE

Comment: Do you think these meters work through spectography or heating of the fluid?